# How to use the column value as main title in grid.arrange?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I created a plotting function that I would like to apply to a list of data frames.

```
plot.sets <- function(x){
  split(x, x$Set) %>%
    lapply(FUN=my.function) -> y
  grid.arrange(grobs=y)
}
```

This works fine and generates several pages of arranged plots. However, I would like the main title on each page to be different. Specifically I would like to do something like this:

```
plot.sets <- function(x){
  split(x, x$Set) %>%
    lapply(FUN=my.function) -> y
  grid.arrange(grobs=y, top=c("Sets for", x$ID))
}
```

For example the page for ID #3 would have the title "Sets for 3." However when I use this code, the title for each page just says "Sets for" and there's no ID number. Any suggestions?

Comment: You may need `top = paste("Sets for", x$ID)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to `paste` the elements inside the function

```
plot.sets <- function(x){
 split(x, x$Set) %>%
   lapply(FUN=my.function) -> y
   grid.arrange(grobs=y, top=paste("Sets for", x$ID))
}
```